# add background image to themeroller theme

Tags: css, themeroller

I am new here and I search for a solution but diddnt find a solution.

I am working on a web app with T/roller theme and I need to set a background image to over ride the theme swatch
I have it working with the following js but the swatch colour shows for a second before the image shows, image is called on page load
I need a way to override to theme

```
 $('div[dsid="logincontainer"]').css('background-image','url("' + Tiggzi.getImagePath('FolderSwitcherBG.png') + '")');
$('div[dsid="logincontainer"]').css('background-size','cover');
$('div[dsid="logincontainer"]').css('background-position','center');
$('div[dsid="logincontainer"]').css('position', 'absolute');
$('div[dsid="logincontainer"]').css('width', '100%');
```

I suppose the question I am asking really is,
is there a way to add an image to the theme that will over ride the swatch colour.

thx for reading

Comment: Is all that code changes property of one image?

Comment: @amaro yes its just js to call the image, cover and centre the image in the container, however the t/roller theme swatch colour shows briefly before the image is in place, looks crap!

Comment: Ok, you can call element once and change all properties:     $(element).css({'property':'value','property':'value', ... }); Maybe you can try to overwrite it with css? It would be helpful if you give us a link or something :)

Comment: @amaro thanks amaro, I cant give link I dont have permission. I tried adding this to the theme .ui-mobile-viewport,div.ui-mobile-viewport {
    background-color:   transparent;
    background-image:   url("files/views/assets/image/FolderSwitcherBG.png");  
    }

Comment: maybe try to create class with those properties just for this particular img, if it wont work try to add !mportant to properties in this class... but Im not sure will it work or is it a good idea.

Comment: .backgroundImg {

background-position: top center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url('../image/FolderSwitcherBG.png');
background-size: cover !important;

}

Comment: I have that and it works, but as I said the swatch colour shows first briefly first

Comment: You should add !important to all elements

Comment: sorry amaro I d,ont understand, I have !important in the css